# How do I view an HTML page that uses Google Maps API v3 locally in a browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm working on the very first example that the "Getting Started" guide mentions. It tells me to type in the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I entered in the API key and set the sensor variable to false. Additionally, I added my IP address to the "Key for server apps." However, when I tried to view the page (by opening the html file with google chrome), it gives me a brief flash of the map and then gives me the popup that says:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
```

I tried looking at several other StackOverflow questions regarding this but none of them seemed to helped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave the API Key. That is not needed for development purpose. Since you are trying to develop google maps application. use the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope, it will help you to develop google maps application.

Have a look at API [access limitation and billing details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) . And also keep it in mind to obtain [api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: wat? api key is needed in v2. dropped in v3

Comment: Thanks! That worked. 

An additional question, if you don't mind, what are API keys used for then? For deployment purposes?

Comment: @albert : Not dropped. We got some space to develop application with their api. Updated my answer with the link which you needed to have a look.

Comment: @Edasaur : Yeap, of course, You are correct. But have to say in other way. API keys are for business purposes, have a look at their documentation which i have shared with you. I hope, it will clear your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Well for this example to work you can remove key from api link as v3 library doesn't require it anymore. So your API link in header will be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```